# Echo specific field from rsform in directory view

Tags: php, joomla, get, echo

my first post here after actively using the site for ages.

I am trying to set up a directory view through RSFORM on my company intranet site. Everything is done, but in directory view i would like to echo the value of one selector in the form (the selector is hidden in the form, and viewable in edit). So when you edit this selector after form submission, it will echo this value to a spesific area of the directory (adds it to class for the whole row).

But I cant figure out how to get spesific field values..

I tried this

```
echo $this->$field(FIELD_NAME);
```

The code section is like this

```
    <?php if ($this->items) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) { ?>
    <tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?> directoryRow **<?php echo $this->$field(FIELD_NAME);  ?>**">
        <?php if ($this->directory->enablecsv) { ?>
            <td align="center" class="center directoryGrid"><?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->SubmissionId); ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->viewableFields as $field) { ?>
            <td align="center" class="center directoryCol directoryCol<?php echo $this->getFilteredName($field->FieldName); ?>"><?php echo $this->getValue($item, $field); ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
```

This is from the view.html.php file

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class RSFormViewDirectory extends JViewLegacy
{
    public function display( $tpl = null ) {
        $this->app          = JFactory::getApplication();
        $this->doc          = JFactory::getDocument();
        $this->document     = &$this->doc;
        $this->params       = $this->app->getParams('com_rsform');
        $this->layout       = $this->getLayout();
        $this->directory    = $this->get('Directory');
        $this->tooltipClass = RSFormProHelper::getTooltipClass();

        if ($this->layout == 'view') {
            $this->doc->addStyleSheet(JHtml::stylesheet('com_rsform/directory.css', array(), true, true));

            $this->template = $this->get('template');
            $this->canEdit  = RSFormProHelper::canEdit($this->params->get('formId'),$this->app->input->getInt('id',0));
            $this->id       = $this->app->input->getInt('id',0);

            // Add custom CSS and JS
            if ($this->directory->JS)
                $this->doc->addCustomTag($this->directory->JS);
            if ($this->directory->CSS)
                $this->doc->addCustomTag($this->directory->CSS);

            // Add pathway
            $this->app->getPathway()->addItem(JText::_('RSFP_SUBM_DIR_VIEW'), '');
        } elseif ($this->layout == 'edit') {
            if (RSFormProHelper::canEdit($this->params->get('formId'),$this->app->input->getInt('id',0))) {
                $this->doc->addStyleSheet(JHtml::stylesheet('com_rsform/directory.css', array(), true, true));
                $this->fields       = $this->get('EditFields');
            } else {
                $this->app->redirect(JURI::root());
            }

            // Add pathway
            $this->app->getPathway()->addItem(JText::_('RSFP_SUBM_DIR_EDIT'), '');
        } else {
            $this->search           = $this->get('Search');
            $this->items            = $this->get('Items');
            $this->uploadFields     = $this->get('uploadFields');
            $this->multipleFields   = $this->get('multipleFields');
            $this->unescapedFields  = array_merge($this->multipleFields, $this->uploadFields);
            $this->fields           = $this->get('Fields');
            $this->headers          = RSFormProHelper::getDirectoryStaticHeaders();
            $this->hasDetailFields  = $this->hasDetailFields();
            $this->hasSearchFields  = $this->hasSearchFields();
            $this->viewableFields   = $this->getViewableFields();
            $this->pagination       = $this->get('Pagination');

            $this->filter_search    = $this->get('Search');
            $this->filter_order     = $this->get('ListOrder');
            $this->filter_order_Dir = $this->get('ListDirn');           

            // Add custom CSS and JS
            if ($this->directory->JS)
                $this->doc->addCustomTag($this->directory->JS);
            if ($this->directory->CSS)
                $this->doc->addCustomTag($this->directory->CSS);
        }

        if ($this->params->get('robots')) {
            $this->document->setMetadata('robots', $this->params->get('robots'));
        }

        if ($this->params->get('menu-meta_description')) {
            $this->document->setDescription($this->params->get('menu-meta_description'));
        }

        if ($this->params->get('menu-meta_keywords')) {
            $this->document->setMetadata('keywords', $this->params->get('menu-meta_keywords'));
        }

        $title = $this->params->get('page_title', '');
        if (empty($title)) {
            $title = JFactory::getConfig()->get('sitename');
        }
        elseif (JFactory::getConfig()->get('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 1) {
            $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', JFactory::getConfig()->get('sitename'), $title);
        }
        elseif (JFactory::getConfig()->get('sitename_pagetitles', 0) == 2) {
            $title = JText::sprintf('JPAGETITLE', $title, JFactory::getConfig()->get('sitename'));
        }

        $this->document->setTitle($title);

        parent::display($tpl);
    }

    protected function hasDetailFields() {
        foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
            if ($field->indetails) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected function hasSearchFields() {
        foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
            if ($field->searchable) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected function getViewableFields() {
        $return = array();

        foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
            if ($field->viewable) {
                $return[] = $field;
            }
        }

        return $return;
    }

    protected function getFilteredName($name) {
        return ucfirst(JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($name));
    }

    protected function getValue($item, $field) {
        if (in_array($field->FieldName, $this->unescapedFields)) {
            return $item->{$field->FieldName};
        } else {
            // Static header?
            if ($field->componentId < 0 && isset($this->headers[$field->componentId])) {
                $header = $this->headers[$field->componentId];
                if ($header == 'DateSubmitted') {
                    $value = RSFormProHelper::getDate($item->$header);
                } else {
                    $value = $item->$header;
                }
            } else {
                // Dynamic header.
                $value = $item->{$field->FieldName};
            }

            return $this->escape($value);
        }
    }

    public function pdfLink($id) {
        $app        = JFactory::getApplication();
        $has_suffix = JFactory::getConfig()->get('sef') && JFactory::getConfig()->get('sef_suffix');
        $pdf_link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsform&view=directory&layout=view&id='.$id.'&format=pdf');
        if ($has_suffix) {
            $pdf_link .= strpos($pdf_link, '?') === false ? '?' : '&';
            $pdf_link .= 'format=pdf';
        }

        return $pdf_link;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say you are using this site for ages you should know how to aks questions. Please provide some code with what you have tried

Comment: @John-Eilif http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you look at the post, my code didnt display on initial publish. I have tried this, and other versions of it, but this is the most relevant one i believe.

Comment: Does it required to have a closing and opening tag in php for each  line ?>
    <?php in line 1 and 2. in the foreach loop you have used several variables like $field, $directory. What are these variable? Where have you defined this?

Comment: These are variables pushed by the component RSFORM itself.